# Need to create title with the list number

Tags: html, css

I need to create the title with the list numbers. But the list numbers are getting mismatch.

```css
h4.heading_numberlist {
    margin-top: 12pt;
    margin-right: 0in;
    margin-bottom: 3pt;
    margin-left: 0in;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Arial",sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h4.heading_numberlist::before {
    content: counter(list-number, decimal) '. ';
}


div.nested3:not(:first-child) {
    counter-increment: list-number;
}
```

```html
<div class="nested2">
    <h3 class="Section_Heading">Section</h3>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_normal">Care</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Services</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Tests</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Number</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

The decimal numbers are starting with 2. But I need to start with Number 1.

Comment: Why don't you use `<ul>` instead?

Comment: This is the expected html, So need to change the style as per htm alone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:first-of-type` instead of `:first-child` to achieve your desired result.

```css
h4.heading_numberlist {
  margin-top: 12pt;
  margin-right: 0in;
  margin-bottom: 3pt;
  margin-left: 0in;
  page-break-after: avoid;
  font-size: 12pt;
  font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h4.heading_numberlist::before {
  content: counter(list-number, decimal) '. ';
}

div.nested3:not(:first-of-type) {
  counter-increment: list-number;
}
```

```html
<div class="nested2">
  <h3 class="Section_Heading">Section</h3>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_normal">Care</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Services</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Tests</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Number</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @User501 : Thanks for asking this question. I had no idea about CSS Counters prior this question. Rated you also. Happy coding

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather for more counter questions refer  this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909448/need-to-create-the-order-list-numbers-and-alphabet-numbers-for-the-title-using-c/62910887#62910887 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62935793/counter-increment-is-not-starting-properly/62935946#62935946

Answer (score 2):

The most natural thing seems to be to reset/initialize the counter and then only increment it where you use it (Robert's answer with a proper selector is also perfectly fine):

```css
body {counter-reset: list-number;}

h4.heading_numberlist {
    margin-top: 12pt;
    margin-right: 0in;
    margin-bottom: 3pt;
    margin-left: 0in;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Arial",sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

h4.heading_numberlist::before {
    content: counter(list-number, decimal) '. ';
    counter-increment: list-number;
}
```

```html
<div class="nested2">
<h3 class="Section_Heading">Section</h3>
<div class="nested3">
<h4 class="heading_normal">Care</h4>
</div>
<div class="nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Services</h4>
</div>
<div class="nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Tests</h4>
</div>
<div class="nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Number</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below solution:

**<kbd>CSS</kbd>**

```
 body{
     counter-reset: my-sec-counter;
   }
    h4.heading_numberlist {
        margin-top: 12pt;
        margin-right: 0in;
        margin-bottom: 3pt;
        margin-left: 0in;
        page-break-after: avoid;
        font-size: 12pt;
        font-family: "Arial",sans-serif;
        color: black;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    h4.heading_numberlist::before {
        counter-increment: my-sec-counter;
        content: "Section " counter(my-sec-counter) ". ";
    }


    div.nested3:not(:first-child) {
      counter-increment: list-number;
    }
```

**<kbd>HTML</kbd>**

```
<body>
    <div class="nested2">
    <h3 class="Section_Heading">Section</h3>
    <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_normal">Care</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Services</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Tests</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="nested3">
    <h4 class="heading_numberlist">Number</h4>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

**What worked?**

Well, basically you had to reset the [`counter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters)

**How ?**

By enclosing all your individual *divs* inside a parent tag (I used `body` tag. But you can use others based on your requirement.)

Then in the CSS, I provided a [`counter-reset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-reset#:%7E:text=The%20counter%2Dreset%20property%20is,The%20keyword%20value%20none%20.) in body tag class like this

```
body{
     counter-reset: my-sec-counter;
   }
```

and then used this reset counter in your  `h4.heading_numberlist::before` like below

```
 h4.heading_numberlist::before {
        counter-increment: my-sec-counter;
        content: "Section " counter(my-sec-counter) ". ";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

That's because of the manipulation of the `div` with the Care section. Change the class according to the solution below.

```css
h4.heading_numberlist {
    margin-top: 12pt;
    margin-right: 0in;
    margin-bottom: 3pt;
    margin-left: 0in;
    page-break-after: avoid;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-family: "Arial",sans-serif;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h4.heading_numberlist::before {
    content: counter(list-number, decimal) '. ';
}


div.nested3:not(:first-child) {
  counter-increment: list-number;
}
```

```html
<div class="nested2">
<h3 class="Section_Heading">Section</h3>
<div>
<h4 class="heading_normal">Care</h4>
</div>
<div class="nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Services</h4>
</div>
<div class="nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Tests</h4>
</div>
<div class="nested3">
<h4 class="heading_numberlist">Number</h4>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeha sorry forgot to remove the class from the parent div of Care section.